# Book about a billionaire geeky mad scientist who creates a zombie apocalypse in order to start a harem

Tags: story-identification, zombie, zombie-apocalypse

In 2015 or 2016, I read a book on the Amazon bookstore that was about a man who created nanobots that infected the human body and turned them into zombies, while using a different "strain" of nanobots to control the minds of women and force them to join his harem. He got ahold of his old highschool bully, and tested the zombie and harem nanobots on the bully and the bully's mother (respectively) before releasing them on the world and starting a full-blown apocalypse.

It was part of a multi-book series, and the first book was free, but I'm not sure what the name of the series, author, or books were, as it's been 4 years since I last read it.

Pretty odd story, but I honestly enjoy reading books set from the villain's perspective (nice toss-up to the genre), so it wasn't too off-putting. Anyway, I've been trying to find it, but as you can imagine, the keywords "zombie, harem, mad-scientist, nanobots" will bring up a ***very*** wide variety of material on Amazon and Google.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like [*Zombie Apocalypse Serial*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007WP2UWW).

The bully part is there according to the amazon description, and the lone wolf who wants to start it.

Haven’t read it but search for “zombie apocalypse harem nano” did the trick.

Comment: Good catch.  Answer could be improved by quoting from some of the reviews further down on the page you linked, that make it clearer that this is the correct book.